# Kibana query to filter out number from logs

Tags: elasticsearch, groovy, kibana

Apologies if the titles sounds ambiguous. My search query is giving results like:

```
log: "your number is 134"
log: "your number is 4300"
log: "your number is 221"
```

I want to filter out the numbers (134, 4300 and 221) out of this search and make some visualizations based on them like Maximum, Minimum and Average of the numbers received in a particular search. I was hit and trial'ing some scripts, but it feels like there are no APIs which could extract me the numbers.

Comment: Can you show the mapping of the index outputting this?

Comment: Thanks for responding. I didn't quite understand what mapping do you want to see, @Miek. Could you please elaborate. The logs are coming to logstash randomly where the number is the only variable.

Comment: When you say you want the numbers filtered out of the search, do you mean you want the documents out of the index entirely, out of search results, or you would like to extract the numbers in such a way that you could create Kibana visualizations? I'm guessing if you want the last option, you could do some simple text parsing and push the number values to their own field on each document, calculating min/max/avg with a numeric field. To help further I think we would need at least some more context about how these log messages are being generated and the ultimate goal for the values.

Comment: @susenj are you are parsing the logs using logstash? normally the data would flow from logstash to elasticsearch then to kibana. You would have to parse those logs in logstash in order to have them "extracted" (indexed)